# why does my wxwidgets app get distorted in windows 8.1

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hi I developed an app that works great in windows xp and windows 7. However once on a Windows 8 64 BIT pc the interfave becomes distorted. Tab heading
s are not fully visible and buttons that were next to each other overlap.

What can I do to sort this out?

Comment: Would you provide either code or a screenshot of what happens please. Preferably both.

Comment: Could be due to Windows scaling. Check your display settings and see if they're set to 100% or something else.

Comment: Guys im using my phone google chrome. How do I upload an image? To explain better the menu bar which contains all my file save options etc seems to be overlapping the below tabs blocking the tab titles. And the buttons get moved slighty left and right.

Comment: Ok the menu bar overlaping the bottom tab goes away when I adjusted the notebook size from height 650 to 600.

Comment: Ok my bet its the fod damn sizer messing every thing up. Thanks guys for the interest. If its not the sizer I will keep u posted